# Modal window over object problem

Tags: css, modal-dialog, html, pdf

I have a problem with displaying modal window of .pdf files in a HTML WebPart.

I have HTML WebPart where I've placed a button (which invokes popup modal window, a file upload, for example) and a pdf in "object" tags (or "iframe", result is the same). When I push the button it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

But I need the pdf to be on background (i.e. under blue shading).
I've already tried to set "wmode" to "transparent" and "opaque" - result is still the same...

How can I make it work properly?

**UPD:** My HTML is:

```
<input type="button" value="Open modal" onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, &quot;http://mysite/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={C9DE9F83-B870-448D-BFCE-622786815E4F}&amp;RootFolder=&quot;);javascript:return false;" "/>
<br/>
<div style="z-index:0;width:500px;height:650px">
  <object type="application/pdf" data="http://mysite/file.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param>
  </object>
</div>
```

**UPD2:** Maybe there were some errors in code, so I've created new page, added new HTML WebPart and added the same code. Now I cannot view my pdf until I remove `<param>` tag ("transparent" or "opaque"), but even if I do it I can see the major problem still presents. Here is my partial DOM, if needed (but I think it looks usually):

```
<tr>
<td class="" valign="top">
<div WebPartID="c465477d-1905-4e05-844a-9ec7140b16b5" HasPers="false" id="WebPartWPQ2" width="100%" class="ms-WPBody ms-wpContentDivSpace" allowDelete="false" style="" >
<input type="button" value="Open modal" onclick="javascript:NewItem2(event, &quot;http://mysite/_layouts/Upload.aspx?List={C9DE9F83-B870-448D-BFCE-622786815E4F}&amp;RootFolder=&quot;);javascript:return false;"/>
<br/>
<div style="z-index:0;width:500px;height:650px">
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://mysite/file.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
</object>
```

Comment: can you add some DOM?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? I've added my html code...

Comment: the DOM is the current HTML rendered by the browser

Comment: I've added it partially, unfortunately I cannot add the whole DOM due to company restrictions.